# C# Apache Arrow - Build an IArrowArray of a list of structs

Tags: c#, apache-arrow

How do I use the C# Apache Arrow library to build an IArrowArray of a list of structs?

```
class Person
{
    public string name;
    public int age;
}

Schema.Builder builder = new Schema.Builder();
var structType = new StructType(
    new []
    {
        new Field("name", new StringType(), nullable: false),
        new Field("age", new Int32Type(), nullable: false)
    });
Field listField = new Field("listOfStructs", new ListType(structField), nullable: false);
builder.Field(listField);
Schema schema = builder.Build();

List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
people.Add(new Person { name = "Alice", age = 30 });
people.Add(new Person { name = "Bob", age = 25 });
people.Add(new Person { name = "Charlie", age = 40 });

// Build IArrowArray
var arrowArray = ...

// length is 1 or size of array data, not sure.
new RecordBatch(schema, arrowArray, length);
```

There is some test code [here](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/45918a90a6ca1cf3fd67c256a7d6a240249e555a/csharp/test/Apache.Arrow.Tests/StructArrayTests.cs) that deals with it starting on line 90, however I don't understand the purpose of the `nullBitmapBuffer` or `offsetsBuffer`.

Comment: If you want to understand the purpose of the null bitmap buffer and the offsets buffer then [this document](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/format/Columnar.html) is the canonical source and a good read if you are going to be working with Arrow.

Every array type in arrow has some number of child arrays and some number of buffers.  A list array has one child array with all the values.  The offsets buffer forms the actual lists.  So if your offsets are [0, 5, 7] then you have two lists, one from index [0-5) and one from index [5-7) of the values array.

Comment: The null bitmap buffer allows you to represent nulls in your array.  If you have a list array there will actually be (at least) 2 null bitmap buffers.  One for your list and one for your items.  So you can have `[[1, 2], null, [null, 4]]` where the first `null` would be represented in the list array's null bitmap and the second `null` would be represented in the child array's null bitmap.

Comment: @Pace thanks for the useful info.  trying to wrap my head around it.  would you be able to show an example using no null fields and using a single list of objects?

Comment: @Pace Should I only set a field's nullBitmap to false (null) when all child fields are null?

Comment: @Pace Whats the purpose of having multiple lists defined by offset?  Cant you have just one big one?

Comment: I will try and create a short example later today.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252853/discussion-between-pace-and-bar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
    var structField = new StructType(
        new []
        {
            new Field("field1", new Int32Type(), nullable: false),
            new Field("field2", new FloatType(), nullable: false)
        });
    
    StringArray stringArray = new StringArray.Builder()
        .AppendRange(new[] {"angel", "bobby", "charlie"})
        .Build();
    Int64Array intArray = new Int64Array.Builder()
        .AppendRange(new[] { 1L,2,3 })
        .Build();
    
    StructArray structs = new StructArray(structField, 3, new IArrowArray[] { stringArray, intArray }, ArrowBuffer.Empty, nullCount: 0);

    var recordBatch = new Apache.Arrow.RecordBatch.Builder()
        .Append("col1", false, structs)
        .Build();

    using (var stream = File.OpenWrite("/Users/bryan/Desktop/test.arrow"))
    using (var writer = new Apache.Arrow.Ipc.ArrowFileWriter(stream, recordBatch.Schema, true))
    {
        await writer.WriteRecordBatchAsync(recordBatch);
        await writer.WriteEndAsync();
    }
```

Comment: This looks mostly correct.  The only thing I would caution is that you specify `structField` as `{int32, float}`.  However, when you create the array you specify `new IArrowArray[] { stringArray, intArray }`.  I believe it is important for these to match (e.g. `new IArrowArray[] { intArray, stringArray }`.

Comment: minor correction: Instead of StringArray it should be FloatArray. So the params for StructArray will be new IArrowArray[] {intArray, floatArray}.